# Contar Resultado do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

olá. boa noite.

estou com uma duvida

quero somar todos os valores do campo `valor_reais` da minha tabela

[image: exemplo]

por exemplo

- `id` 1 = 150
- `id` 2 = 100
- `id` 3 = 100

quero o resultado obvio, 350

ja tentei algo como:

```
$buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela");
$buscar->execute();
$valor = $buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$quantidade = $buscar->rowCount();
$valor_final = $valor->valor_reais;
echo $quantidade * $valor_final;
```

mas está retornando 450

Comment: se quer somar, por que está multiplicando pela quantidade???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só utilizar a função agregada do sql: **SUM**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor_reais) as total FROM tabela");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo $row->total;
```

Comment: Como eu imprimo isto?

Comment: Editei a resposta para você ver.

Answer (score 4):

O "resultado óbvio" está correto. Você está exibindo:

```
$quantidade * $valor_final
```

Que... adivinhe. É `450`, resultado de `(3 * 150)`

Uma alternativa para somar seria simplesmente:

```
SELECT SUM(campo) FROM tabela
```

Ou fazer um `loop` nos resultados, efetivamente fazendo uma soma:

```
$buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela");
$buscar->execute();

$valor_final = 0; // Iniciamos com zero                                  
while ($valor = $buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { // percorremos cada linha
  $valor_final += $valor->valor_reais;            // e adicionamos ao valor_final
}
echo $valor_final;
```

(ajuste as variáveis ao seu caso real)